# VBA-Excel Converting "FALSE" string to "False"

Tags: vba, excel

This problem is driving me crazy! I have the following VBA Excel code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim sTempVal As String

For i = 1 to 100
    sTempVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    MsgBox sTempVal
Next i
```

As it is looping down the values in the first column, if it comes across the value FALSE or the value TRUE, it automatically reads it in as "False" or "True". Why is VBA changing the case automatically?? I really need it to retain the exact case of that value in the cell. I thought that by Dim'ing the sTempVal variable as a string, it would just read in the value in the cell - case and everything. Note that this ONLY applies to FALSE and TRUE. Any other value will be read in exactly as it appears in the cell.

Answer (score 10):

```
Sub Test()

Dim sTempVal As String

For i = 1 to 100
    sTempVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text
    MsgBox sTempVal
Next i
```

**.Text** is *"What you see is what you get."*

**EDIT#1:**

When you use `.Value` VBA reads the item as a Boolean and, when converting to a string, it uses its own convention for that conversion.
For example, if you pick a cell and enter the formula:

```
=1=1
```

and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub WhatIsTruth()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

you will see:

[image]

Using `.Text` avoids this problem.

Comment: Can you add a quick line explaining for the OP why this is happening with `.Value` as they did specifically ask that question?

Comment: Ta for that.  Just helps the OP understand better :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. I can't believe I've been using VBA for like five years on some pretty complex stuff, and I've never known about the Cells.Text property. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

`Range.Value` returns a `Variant`, not a `String`. You're assigning it to a `String` variable, so it is implicitly cast.

This line...

```
sTempVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
```

...is equivalent to:

```
sTempVal = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)
```

VBA's cast from `Boolean` to `String` is proper cased - Excel's cast is upper cased.  For example:

```
Debug.Print CStr(0 = 0) 'Prints "True"
```

If you want Excel's string representation of what is in the cell, you can use the `Range.Text` property instead:

```
sTempVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text
```